# Unit testing mvc model with HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5, nunit, moq

In my MVC5 application, I have a Log entity, that is used to log any call to any controler. This log uses: `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()` to determine the identity of the user accessing the controller.

```cs
public class Log
{
    public Log()
    {
        TS = DateTime.Now;
        UserId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
    }

    [Required]
    public Int32 Id  { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "TS", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Models.Log.Log))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Models.Log.Log), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredTS")]
    public DateTime TS { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public short LogTypeId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "LogText", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Models.Log.Log))]
    public string LogText { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to unit test a controller and crating an instance of the log class I get this error:

> threw exception:  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>       at DASU.Core.Models.Log..ctor()

I know this is because the context is not set.

So my question is how do I set the context, or how do I mock the context, so I can create the Log for my test?

Comment: Are you using any IoC / DI container? If you are, it's best to get the user from that. You can have a web filter that puts the user from the `HttpContext` into the container. And you can have a test setup that puts the user from the test context into the container. Obviously this doesn't apply to unit tests, since they don't care about users. This is just for integration tests. If you have a unit under test which unavoidably calls out to another unit during test (in your case, Log and HttpContext are other units) then you're not unit testing. Separate your units better.

Comment: It would be far easier to require the userId as a parameter of the constructor instead of keeping a hidden dependency like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid coupling to `HttpContext`. Like suggested in the comments you could simplify your log my injecting the `UserId` into the dependent Log class

```cs
public class Log
{
    public Log(string userId)
    {
        TS = DateTime.Now;
        UserId = userId;
    }

    //...other code removed for brevity
}
```

or abstracting away the calls to `HttpContext` so that you can mock your abstract and inject that instead of trying and mock `HttpContext`

```cs
public interface IUserProvider {
    string GetUserId();
}
```

You production implementations can wrap calls to `HttpContext` and you can easily create mock implementations for your unit tests.

```cs
public class Log
{
    public Log(IUserProvider userProvider)
    {
        TS = DateTime.Now;
        UserId = userProvider.GetUserId();
    }

    //...other code removed for brevity
}
```